# calculating retention within the same table in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a below SQL table like below:-

```
Date                       domain     user
2021-02-03 08:35:07 UTC    abc        foo@abc.com
```

I want to calculate retention. Like the total unique number of users from first week who are also present in the next week or What percent of unique users from week 1 are present in week 2.

It would be great if I can calculate it for several weeks like months or 6 months after providing the period. Even for month will help me.

Comment: Your question is rather broad.  Specific examples of what you want would really help -- as would a consistent database tag.

Comment: The date column is a time series and I want to calculate how many users from the first week are present in 2nd week. or what percent of unique users from the first week present in 2nd week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate unique users per week into arrays, then count the intersection between current week's users with previous week's users:

```
with mytable as (
  select timestamp '2021-02-03 08:35:07' as date, 'foo1@abc.com' as user union all
  select timestamp '2021-02-03 08:35:07' as date, 'foo2@abc.com' as user union all
  select timestamp '2021-02-10 08:35:07' as date, 'foo2@abc.com' as user union all
  select timestamp '2021-02-10 08:35:07' as date, 'foo3@abc.com' as user union all
  select timestamp '2021-02-10 08:35:07' as date, 'foo4@abc.com' as user union all
  select timestamp '2021-02-17 08:35:07' as date, 'foo3@abc.com' as user union all
  select timestamp '2021-02-17 08:35:07' as date, 'foo4@abc.com' as user union all
  select timestamp '2021-02-17 08:35:07' as date, 'foo5@abc.com' as user union all
  select timestamp '2021-02-24 08:35:07' as date, 'foo5@abc.com' as user
),
users_per_week as (
  select
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(date, WEEK) as week,
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT user) as users
  from mytable
  group by week
),
with_prev_week_users as (
  select
    week,
    lag(users) over (order by week) as prev_users,
    users
  from users_per_week
)
select 
  week,
  prev_users,
  users,
  ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY(select * from unnest(prev_users) intersect distinct select * from unnest(users))) as retention,
from with_prev_week_users
```

[image]

Comment: in the first few lines you are doing union all on every single row what you will do when you have millions of those rows.

Comment: Also how I can run this on a particular period of time as I have years and years of data. Like if I want to run this for march or for march and April or for any time period/

Comment: `union all` are used only to populate `mytable` which is just an example input data.

Comment: If you want to run this for March and April just add filter on the `date` column to the `users_per_week` like: `select TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(date, WEEK) as week, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT user) as users from mytable where date >= TIMESTAMP '2021-03-01 00:00:00' and date < TIMESTAMP '2021-05-01 00:00:00'  group by week`

Comment: One last question. can we get something like domain and retention rate from weeks 1 to 2 week 2 to 3 because I have millions of users. 

domain Week1 to week 2  week2 to week 3

foo           56%                      76%

foo1         67%                      63%

Comment: Hmm... Not sure if I follow... Could you paste an example input data with expected output? Better do it in a separate question though, so that others would look at it too.